# Getting value from object in javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

After `console.log(item)` I got following object.

```
Object {_value: "106", _id: "opt_zXtP8TOfW2zteOgDIJQDI6Bxx3xSTkl5", _class: "selected", _selected: "selected"}
```

I want `_value` from this object. How can I do this?

I tried `alert(item.value)` but gets undefined

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're ignoring the underscore. `value` and `_value` are not the same. You need to use:

```
item["_value"];
```

Or:

```
item._value;
```